# Cloud build fails for ios sdk target 12.1

Tags: nativescript, sidekick

Build in sidekick for ios always fails when targeting sdk 12.1. Hoped updating to latest nativescript and sidekick would resolve this problem but it is still there. Android works fine.

I have updated nativescript and sidekick and xcode to latest version, migrated my project. Tried remove/add tns platforms, remove/install xcode, updating components. Problem still persists.

Any help would be much appreciated :)

tns doctor says:

```
✔ Your ANDROID_HOME environment variable is set and points to correct directory.  
✔ Your adb from the Android SDK is correctly installed.  
✔ The Android SDK is installed.  
✔ A compatible Android SDK for compilation is found.  
✔ Javac is installed and is configured properly.  
✔ The Java Development Kit (JDK) is installed and is configured properly.  
✔ Xcode is installed and is configured properly.  
✔ xcodeproj is installed and is configured properly.  
✔ CocoaPods are installed.  
✔ CocoaPods update is not required.  
✔ CocoaPods are configured properly.  
✔ Your current CocoaPods version is newer than 1.0.0.  
✔ Python installed and configured correctly.  
✔ The Python 'six' package is found.  
✔ Xcode version 10.3.0 satisfies minimum required version 10.  
✔ Getting NativeScript components versions information...  
✔ Component nativescript has 6.0.2 version and is up to date.  
✔ Component tns-core-modules has 6.0.2 version and is up to date.  
⚠ Update available for component tns-android. Your current version is 6.0.0 and the latest available version is 6.0.1.  
✔ Component tns-ios has 6.0.1 version and is up to date.
```

Dependencies in json.package file:

```
"dependencies": {  
    "@types/node": "^12.6.8",  
    "axios": "^0.19.0",  
    "nativescript-barcodescanner": "^3.2.1",  
    "nativescript-platform-css": "1.6.9",  
    "nativescript-theme-core": "1.0.6",  
    "nativescript-vue": "2.4.0",   
    "tns-core-modules": "^6.0.2", 
    "tslib": "^1.10.0",  
    "vuex": "^3.1.1"  
  },  
  "devDependencies": {  
    "@babel/core": "7.4.5",  
    "@babel/preset-env": "7.4.5",  
    "babel-loader": "~8.0.6",  
    "nativescript-dev-webpack": "1.0.2",  
    "nativescript-vue-template-compiler": "~2.4.0",  
    "node-sass": "4.12.0",  
    "tns-core-modules-widgets": "^6.0.1",  
    "tns-platform-declarations": "^6.0.2",  
    "typescript": "3.4.5",  
    "vue-loader": "~15.7.1"  
  },
```

Error output:

> [19-07-29 11:38:37.271] (CLI) ** ARCHIVE FAILED **   [19-07-29
>   11:38:37.271] (CLI) The following build commands failed:   [19-07-29
>   11:38:37.271] (CLI) \tProcessPCH
>   /tmp/builds/*/e0e933b61c66a857c8413163ff98f28c705b345f/6.0.2/6.0.1/VetZooExpress/platforms/ios/DerivedData/VetZooExpress/Build/Intermediates.noindex/ArchiveIntermediates/VetZooExpress/PrecompiledHeaders/SharedPrecompiledHeaders/5472762253979011612/VetZooExpress-Prefix.pch.gch
>   /tmp/builds/*/e0e933b61c66a857c8413163ff98f28c705b345f/6.0.2/6.0.1/VetZooExpress/platforms/ios/VetZooExpress/VetZooExpress-Prefix.pch normal armv7 objective-c com.apple.compilers.llvm.clang.1_0.compiler
>   [19-07-29 11:38:37.271] (CLI) (1 failure)   [19-07-29 11:38:37.271]
>   (CLI) [xcode-build] The armv7 architecture is deprecated for your
>   deployment target (iOS 12.1). You should update your ARCHS build
>   setting to remove the armv7 architecture. (in target 'VetZooExpress') 
>   [19-07-29 11:38:37.271] (CLI) [xcode-build] clang: error: invalid iOS
>   deployment version '-miphoneos-version-min=12.1', iOS 10 is the
>   maximum deployment target for 32-bit targets
>   [-Winvalid-ios-deployment-target]   [19-07-29 11:38:38.710] (CLI) **
>   ARCHIVE FAILED **   [19-07-29 11:38:38.710] (CLI) The following build
>   commands failed:   [19-07-29 11:38:38.710] (CLI) \tProcessPCH
>   /tmp/builds/*/e0e933b61c66a857c8413163ff98f28c705b345f/6.0.2/6.0.1/VetZooExpress/platforms/ios/DerivedData/VetZooExpress/Build/Intermediates.noindex/ArchiveIntermediates/VetZooExpress/PrecompiledHeaders/SharedPrecompiledHeaders/5472762253979011612/VetZooExpress-Prefix.pch.gch
>   /tmp/builds/*/e0e933b61c66a857c8413163ff98f28c705b345f/6.0.2/6.0.1/VetZooExpress/platforms/ios/VetZooExpress/VetZooExpress-Prefix.pch normal armv7 objective-c com.apple.compilers.llvm.clang.1_0.compiler
>   [19-07-29 11:38:38.710] (CLI) (1 failure)   [19-07-29 11:38:49.823]
>   Build step completed.

Comment: This may be helpful https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50768723/what-does-warning-mapping-architecture-arm64-to-x86-64-mean

Comment: Thx @Narendra I realize now this must be a Sidekick cloud error. Managed finally to get it working doing local build with the CLI instead.