# Why No architectures to compile for (ONLY_ACTIVE_ARCH=YES, active arch=arm64, VALID_ARCHS=)

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, xcode

Cannot get my app to compile. Getting this warning.

Tried everything in [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50768723/what-does-warning-mapping-architecture-arm64-to-x86-64-mean), but still will not fix the issue. Is there a way to search for what dependecy is the issue?

```
No architectures to compile for (ONLY_ACTIVE_ARCH=YES, active arch=arm64, VALID_ARCHS=).
```

Target Settings (the Project Settings look the same)

[image]

Comment: Why set Valid Architectures to blank? It's shown as the solution in the question you linked, but that seems incorrect... mine shows "arm64 arm64e, armv7 armv7s"