# Flutter iOS run give Multiple Commands produce Runner

Tags: flutter, flutter-ios

Everything was working fine, until this morning when I added a new package (apple_sign_in) to my pubspec.yaml and tried to run on iOS.  Now I get the following output:
[image]

Ive tried the two common approaches that I see with similar errors and switch to legacy build system.  Also looked at the embedded framework, but I dont have any embedded frameworks on my project

[image]

Not sure what is causing this issue or how to fix it.  Also if I try to build it (not run it) I get this warning

[image]

Ive been trying everyting and cant seem to figure this out.  Please help

Comment: delete the Podfile and regenerate it. Also ensure platform number is valid for the requirement of the plugin.

Comment: tried that, still get the first error

Comment: Try: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50768723/what-does-warning-mapping-architecture-arm64-to-x86-64-mean

Comment: And also try delete podfile.lock and pods folder then install the plugin.

Comment: Also try here: https://github.com/tomgilder/flutter_apple_sign_in/issues/34

Comment: Still get the same error with all of those options